# Como consumir API's em java utilizando Spring boot

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

estudo java mais especificamente spring boot e gostaria de aprender a consumir api's. Alguem tem algum material atualizado que eu possa fazer isso? Por exemplo consumir api da marvel ou  CEP. Procurei tudo pelo Youtube mas nao estou conseguindo entender pq cada pessoa faz de um jeito diferente, queria algo organizado pra entender do início ao fim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns itens que talvez possam variar de tutorial para tutorial são: o design da aplicação, e o client HTTP utilizado. O Spring framework fornece o SpringMVC, que possui alguns clients HTTP:

- [Spring WebClient](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient)
- [Spring RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) (Descontinuado)

Se procura por algo atualizado, pesquise pelo WebClient.

Você também tem a opção de utilizar as bibliotecas de clients HTTP Java, como:

- HttpClient
- Apache HttpClient
- OkHttpClient

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).